# Generating Function for edge-rooted labelled trees

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees

Let $T_v(z)$ be the (exponential) generating function for vertex-rooted (non-plane) trees.

Im trying to construct the generating function $T_e(z)$ for edge-rooted trees from this.

I know the coefficients for these GFs are well known, I'm trying to verify that my idea is correct, since i'd like to use it on more specific cases of trees (bounded maximum degree and such).

So my idea was taking a designated edge, which is the same as 2 vertices, so that translates to $2z$ in the GF world. Then add a vertex-labelled tree on to each of the vertices, in the GF world that should give a factor $(T_v(z))^2$.
So I get:
$$T_e(z) = 2z(T_v(z))^2$$

Is this correct?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't look correct; you can add a forest of trees to each end of the designated edge (since the two new vertices are external to what is added). It's probably simpler just to take two vertex-rooted trees and identify the roots as the ends of the designated edge, giving $T_e(z)=T_v(z)^2$.

Comment: We've both assumed that the edge-root is oriented (i.e. the two ends are distinguishable). If it isn't, then we need to discard one of each asymmetric pair, which gives $T_e(z)=\frac{1}{2}(T_v(z)^2+T_v(z^2))$.

Comment: Thank you! Considering labelled trees, are the ends not distinguishable even when the edge is not oriented?

Comment: Yes, of course; the labels induce an orientation (of every edge). You didn't state that you were considering labelled trees, but you did state that $T_v(z)$ was the _exponential_ generating function, so that should have been evident.